# Memory warning and crashes, but no leaks

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, instruments

I'm creating an app based on storyboard, where each of the views has quite a lot of large images. The app crashes (not a lot, it usually crashes after 10-15 minutes of intensive use) after having displayed a few memory warning. 
I've checked instruments, and it's not reporting any single memory leak. Also, the allocation seems to be reasonable (I've only got 1 or 2 peaks in the game when I load some very xib containing very big images - around 8mo for the iPad retina version). 
I don't really have any objects I can release when I receive a memory warning, as all the stuff from the previous view has already been deallocated.

I've seen that similar problem, but it seems to be related to a specific line of code, which is not my case : [iOS - App crashing after Memory Warning - Instruments showing no leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698055/ios-app-crashing-after-memory-warning-instruments-showing-no-leaks)

Is there a way to force xcode to clean the images that are cached?
Otherwise, what can I do to prevent these crashes?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you post some code showing us how you release images?

Comment: Check the creation and release of images. CFRelease, CGContextRelease etc could be required.

Comment: Leaks aren't the only thing that cause memory warnings. It looks like you're receiving them purely from memory consumption. My first though would be to use images sized for the screen and not 8MP images.

Comment: It's UIImageViews contained in a xib file, some of them are referenced as IBOutlets, and released in the dealloc, some others are just on the xib file and not referenced in the code at all, and I assume that Xcode is supposed to release them at some point. If possible, I'd like to be able to remove it from cache. Also, most of the time, I'm using images sized for the screen, but at some point I've got a huge zoomable image. That's why it's 8Mo.

Comment: This could be useful reading. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html Try the `applicationDidRecieveMemoryWarning` and/or override the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I know about these applicationDidRecieveMemoryWarning and didReceiveMemoryWarning functions, but as I told earlier, my problem is to know what to release in it, as all the images that are not being used anymore are supposed to have been released by xcode when moving to the next viewController.

Comment: Probably not, because they are your problem if you aren't using ARC AFAIK. Try using dealloc or viewDidUnload to release your objects yourself, unless its already done.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the similar problem, but my solution was at the end easy:
You should think the Iphone is like a car. A car can't speed up to 100 Mph in one second. A Iphone can't load big images in one second. So what you have to do is: you should shrink the size of the images and if there are more than 2 big images on one view just delete one of them or put it to other views.

If that is not your solution look for mistakes in the code and check up, where the app crashes.